# Get full svn error when running from powershell

Tags: powershell, svn

Setup:
Add a new file, do an svn add, and then delete the file so you get an svn missing error:

```
c:\path\trunk\svn commit
C:\path\trunk>svn commit svn: E155010: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155010: 'C:\path\trunk\New Text Document.txt' is scheduled for
addition, but is missing
```

However, if you run this same command from powershell you get the following instead:

```
PS>&svn commit
svn.exe : svn: E155010: Commit failed (details follow):
At line:1 char:1
+ &svn commit
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (svn: E155010: C...etails follow)::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

You'll notice the powershell output never displays the referenced "details follow".  Is there a way to show the full output from the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get identical output in powershell and cmd prompt when following your steps. Both produce:

```
svn: E155010: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155010: 'C:\temp\trunk\test.txt' is scheduled for addition, but is missing
```

Powershell isn't getting an error record. This is using Tortoise SVN 1.9.7 in Powershell 5.1. That being said you may be able to get further details by looking in $error[0] and checking the Exception property.

```
$error[0].Exception | Select-object *
```

Comment: Thank you for answering - confirming that it SHOULD work that way, help me look at other options...

The issue is $ErrorActionPreference.  I'm currently working in ISE which seems to have it set to "Stop" by default.  When I switch it to "Continue" which is the default for the non-ise shell, it diesplays as expected.  Thought it still displays a bit differently than yours...displays still as I have above with the exception info, and then the additional svn info at the bottom.